# Where will I configure Distributed Cache in multi server farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache, appserver-index-server

This is not a programming question.

Am stuck with the below:
in my Prod.,[ this is a multi server Prod.Farm ], am having 2 INDEX servers and 
2 WFEs been provisioned.

In which server, I need to configure Distributed Cache?
whether it should be in WFE1 & WFE2 or INDEX1 & INDEX2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly recommended configure the Distributed Cache on the WFEs (in your Case WF1 & WFE2). In SharePoint 2016, we have a min role WFE with Distributed Cache.

DC stores login token issues by Security token service which are required by the WFE in order to authenticate the users. If the DC on WFE then it will be quick.

But you have to configure the Memory utilization on the DC, recommend is 10% of the server available.

Here are couple of good articles related for DC. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#memory

and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396